# Formatting individual cells on a w2ui grid with dinamic data (no fixed rows)

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I have a w2ui grid that shows data from a remote server (json data). I'm managing the 'onload' event to, dinamically, iterate over records and apply colors to some cells.

The idea is: search inside the values of each record, and apply some style if some cell has a determinated text.

To do that, I manage the onLoad event, when completed I do a call to a javascript function that iterates over rows and apply cell style. No problem with this process and all works fine.

The problem is when I click in some column header and sort data. The style is lost. Well, I tried to manage onRefresh, onSort events and call the 'format' function. The function is called, but finally the cells lose the style I apply in the function.

```
w2ui['grid'].on('load', function (event) {
console.log("grid instanciado");

        //Se lanza cuando ya tiene records
        event.done(function () {
            console.log("datos cargados en el grid");
            format();//works great here
        });
    });//end load

    w2ui.grid.on('sort', function (event) {
        console.log("ordenado");
        event.done(function () {
            console.log("ordenado DONE");
            //format();//I've tried in different events, nothing works
        });
    });//end sort

    w2ui.grid.on('refresh', function (event) {
        console.log("refrescado");
        format();//I've tried in different events, nothing works
    });//end refresh

    w2ui.grid.on('render', function (event) {
        console.log("renderizado");

        event.onComplete = function () {
            console.log("renderizado COMPLETADO");
        }
        //format();  //I've tried in different events, nothing works
    });//end render


//apply style to a cell
function format() {

    console.log("aplicando formato");

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < w2ui['grid'].total; i++) {
        //get cell                       
        var nombreCelda = "#grid_grid_data_";
        nombreCelda = nombreCelda.concat(String(i));
        nombreCelda = nombreCelda.concat("_4");//pos columna

        if ($(nombreCelda) != undefined) {
            if ($(nombreCelda).text() === 'Closed') {  //regla 1
                console.log("... aplicando color Closed a " + nombreCelda);
                $(nombreCelda).css('background-color', '#eb766d');
            }
            else if ($(nombreCelda).text() === 'Open') { //regla 2
                console.log("... aplicando color Open a " + nombreCelda);
                $(nombreCelda).css('background-color', '#c5f4e2');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When loading, the code works fine. When sorting, the function is called, by the style is not applied.

The call stack when sorting is:
on.sort -> on.sort.done -> on.refresh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom color to w2ui cell \[Grid\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696758/add-custom-color-to-w2ui-cell-grid)

Comment: Not the same case. I customize color  of cells with DINAMIC data (json received from remote server), not fixed rows.

Comment: But the idea is the same. You pre-process the records (in your case in JS instead of on the server side), adding the styling information as shown in the linked question/answer and then the cells will be colored / styled (Note that single cells can be styled, not just rows). It would be helpful if you provide a link to a working jsfiddle, a [mcve].

Comment: No, is not. The records in my scenario are no hardcoded, there is no lines 'records' in my code. The style is setted like this: records: [
    { recid: 1, fname: 'Jane', lname: 'Doe', class: 'my-css-class-for-the-row', style: {3: 'background-color: yellow; color: white;'} }           
];   //the style property

Comment: The way I get data for the grid is calling a remote net core controller:  w2ui['grid'].load('/controllername/GetData');

Comment: I fully understand. That's why I said you should pre-process the data (in the ``onLoad`` event) **before** the grid is rendering the records.

Comment: Are you saying that , when I receive the json data from the server, create on the fly a 'records' group with all the data , simulating 'hardcoded' records ?

Comment: Your JSON should already be in the form ``{status: x, success: y, records: [a,b,c]}`` (according to the [w2grid data structure description](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/grid)) so yes, my suggestion is you modify those records in JS and add the styling information before the records are rendered. Then the grid will do the coloring for you.

Comment: But onRender is not called when sorting, I think-.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to modify json records on the onLoad.done event:

```
w2ui['grid'].on('load', function (event) {
        console.log("grid instanciado");

        //Se lanza cuando ya tiene records
        event.done(function () {
            console.log("datos cargados en el grid");
            //format();
            format2(w2ui['grid'].records);
        });
    });


function format2(records) {

    if (typeof records === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    console.log("aplicando formato 2");
    console.log("total records: " + records.length);

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)  {

        var record = records[i];

        var estado = record['estado'];

        if (typeof estado === 'undefined') {
            return
        }


        //style: {3: 'background-color: red; color: white;'}
        if (estado == 'Closed') {
            var estilo = { "4": 'background-color: red; color: white;' };
            record["style"] = estilo;
        }
        //style: {3: 'background-color: green; color: black;'}
        else if (estado == 'Open') {
            var estilo = { "4": 'background-color: green; color: black;' };
            record["style"] = estilo;
        }

        console.log("aplicado estilo al registro " + String(i));
    }
}
```

[image: The cell color is not changed]

The cell color is not changed. The javascript console says that the json elements contains the style:

[image: Json records]

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
w2ui.grid.on('refresh', function (event) {
        console.log("refrescado");
        format2(w2ui['grid'].records);
    });


function format2(records) {

    if (typeof records === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    console.log("aplicando formato 2");
    console.log("total records: " + records.length);

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++)  {

        var record = records[i];

        var estado = record['estado'];

        if (typeof estado === 'undefined') {
            return
        }

        if (estado == 'Closed') {

            //apply to column 'estado' the style
            var estilo2 = { estado: 'background-color: red; color: white;' };
            record["w2ui"] = {
                style: estilo2
            };

            //Not necesary
            //w2ui['grid'].refreshCell(record["recid"], "estado");
        }
        //style: {3: 'background-color: green; color: black;'}
        else if (estado == 'Open') {

            var estilo2 = { estado: 'background-color: green; color: black;' };
            record["w2ui"] = {
                style: estilo2
            };

            //Not necesary
            //w2ui['grid'].refreshCell(record["recid"], "estado");
        }

        console.log("aplicado estilo al registro " + String(i));
    }
}
```